# Parsing JSON from nested result android

Tags: android, json

Here is my code:

```
try{
        JSONObject jsonObjitem = new JSONObject(jsonString);
        JSONArray phrasemaster = jsonObjitem.getJSONArray("phrases");
       for(int i = 0; i<phrasemaster.length();i++){
            JSONObject scan = phrasemaster.getJSONObject(i);
            int id = scan.getInt("id");

           if (id == current){
               String question = scan.getString("question");
               idoutcome1 = scan.getString("idoutcome1");
               idoutcome2 = scan.getString("idoutcome2");
               idoutcome3 = scan.getString("idoutcome3");
           }
         }


    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

The user on launch gets random number, when he press the button he is being moved to another fragment where this number is used to pull item from JSON, this number serves as id. 
Each item have another three id's. So when I pull my item with this code I also pull 3 id's from that json item. Now what I want is to output the question string from these id's.

```
 {
  "phrases": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "question": "first item",
      "idoutcome1": 2,
      "idoutcome2": 3,
      "idoutcome3": 4
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "nameofoption": "item 2",
      "question": "some question 2",
      "idoutcome1": 5,
      "idoutcome2": 6,
      "idoutcome3": 7
    },
    {
      "id": 3,
      "nameofoption": "item 3",
      "question": "some question 3",
      "idoutcome1": 8,
      "idoutcome2": 9,
      "idoutcome3": 10
    }
]
}
```

The thing is that I don't understand how I can reach out to these values.

Edit: illustration of what I'm trying to do.
While parsing I take the idoutcome1,2,3 values and output them on my buttons. 
However, I want to output the value written in the nameofoption field instead of these numbers. Just like the example, instead of 2 it should show "left".

The problem is that I have this try that searches for id that it got on the previous page and outputs item with corresponding id. How can I implement it within the course of this try that it would go deeper and depending on the idoutcome's of this JSON item display values from the nameofoption field?
[image: explanation]

Comment: Question isn't clear... Where is the json parsing code in relation to everything else? Why can't you call a method to pass the data to wherever you need it?

Comment: you are pulling out the value question y cant you use it? (because String question is local variable)

Comment: @cricket_007 please see edit

Comment: @jagapathi I have no trouble of using the question, please see edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved it in a following way, all of the idoutcome's were put in arraylist, then I've reused the same json parsing code to loop through the items with the respective id's and then output them ti the buttons with settext. 
That was my first json experience, thanks for the downvotes.